# Positioning issue with navigation in slider

Tags: css, positioning

I have a positioning issue which I cannot solve...

I've generated a JQuery slider with the [JQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) and I try to add some navigation bullets, which should be in the middle of the slide. But for some reason, the `<div id="nav">` doesn't respond to the normal positioning elements...

My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="homepage-slider">
    <ul class="slider-elements">
       <li><img src="http://path/to/my/image.jpg" /></li>
       <li><img src="http://path/to/my/image.jpg" /></li>
       <li><img src="http://path/to/my/image.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="nav" class="homepage-slider-navigation">
       <a href=""></a>
       <a href=""></a>
       <a href=""></a>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.homepage-slider {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.homepage-slider #nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -60px;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.homepage-slider #nav a {
  background: url('images/slider_navigation.png');
  background-position: -22px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}

.homepage-slider #nav a.activeSlide {
  background: url('images/slider_navigation.png');
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried with things like `margin: auto`, `text-align: center`, `position`,... But I think I'm missing something here. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Typo on `<div id="#nav">`? You don't need the `#` prefixing the `id` in the markup.

Comment: Typo indeed. The `#` is not in the HTML

Comment: Please can you create a demo? The HTML in the question is missing a closing `</div>` and any `<a>` elements, so it's difficult to recreate your problem.

Comment: I've updated the question... A demo is rather difficult since I'm in my car right now...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '#' in the div ID:

```
<div id="nav" class="homepage-slider-navigation">
```

Comment: That's a typo in the question. Sorry